# How would I pass parameters to a parent class when creating an assembly reference of a child class?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have autism so I'm sorry if this question is dumb or if you struggle to understand what I'm trying to say. I'm also bad at explaining things, but here it goes:

Structure of my code that is relevant to my problem for context:

```
    //Debug startup class
    //Live startup class

    //abstract ProjectBaseClass
    //abstract TemplateBaseClass : abstract ProjectBaseClass
    //abstract TemplateHandlerClass : abstract TemplateBaseClass 
    //TemplateClass : abstract TemplateHandlerClass
```

The project I'm working on has 200+ templates created already, and I've run into a dilemma. I need to pass a parameter to `ProjectBaseClass`, but I would prefer not to update the 200 templates to do this, and this parameter needs to be passed on creation of `TemplateClass`.

`TemplateClass` is created using Assembly, this happens in `Debug` like this

```
var templateName = "NameOfTemplate";
var assembly = typeof(TemplateBaseClass).Assembly;
var classes = assembly.GetTypes().ToList();
var templateType = classes.Single(Object => Object.Name.Equals(templateName));
var template = (TemplateBase)Activator.CreateInstance(templateType);
```

So, how would I pass a parameter down to the `ProjectBaseClass` constructor from `Activator.CreateInstance(templateType)` without messing with any of the `TemplateClass` constructors?

If this is a bad question, just let me know and I'll delete it :)

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange!  I have removed the incorrect tag "assembly" from your post.  When you type a tag a description appears which shows what it is for.  "assembly" is for assembly language, not making assemblies.

Comment: Unfortunately, you will have to modify the constructors of all those base classes so that when you construct `TemplateClass` and pass a parameter value to it, that value can be passed to base constructors which eventually pass it to the constructor of `ProjectBaseClass`. Perhaps you would be better served by using objects to hold properties that are passed down, instead of individual parameters? It would certainly be easier to extend.

Comment: Yeah, I think y'all are right. I figured out how to make it work with default parameters instead of forced parameters, so it's better than nothing. Thanks for your time! And thanks for the edit @TomV !

Comment: Your question is not bad at all, please do *not delete it :)